# Sharepoint list vs SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sharepoint

I am about to work on an LOB application for my customer. The asp.net web application has to be hosted on their on-premise Sharepoint server. In the past, I have created data entry forms using Infopath and designed workflows using Sharepoint designer tool but I have limited amount of experience on sharepoint development.

Project requirement:
1. An input screen for the users to enter data that will be stored in a data store such as SQL Server?
2. A dashboard to indicate the status of their submitted requests.
3. Application has to be hosted on Sharepoint server (on-premise at the moment). But I would like to know what if at later point, they decide to move it to Office 365 (cloud)? Will it be easier to migrate the application including any workflows that are created?

What I need advise on? Here are some of my questions:

1. Data store (SQL Server vs Sharepoint list) - Which one is better? For a typical LOB application such as this one, will it make sense to store the data in SQL Server or Sharepoint list?
2. Performance - Will it overtime degrade the performance of the application if the data is stored in Sharepoint list instead of SQL Server? What would be an ideal choice? Is Sharepoint list used as a data store for some very specific scenarios only and what are those scenarios? Amount of this application’s data is expected to grow as the time goes by. Probably, say there will be almost 30000 records added each month and may be more later?
3. Security - Is Sharepoint list a secure option for storing data? I know that a sharepoint admin can provide access to a sharepoint list if anyone desires that would enable people to modify the structure of the list or mess up with the data through sharepoint.

As i have limited experience on sharepoint, I need advise on whether to use list or SQL Server to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

If your LOB Application has complex structure like tables with very relations and two or more linked table by relation , SharePoint will got you in trouble.

If you like to make summary report from all tables with complex join , it's better to use SQL Server.
Simple answer is SharePoint development with multiple linked tables is hard and software maintenance is hard too.

Performance: SharePoint list with very large of data (above 500000 record) will be slow depend on hardware on server performance , But you can use large list patterns if you like this url [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-lists-V-Techniques-for-managing-large-lists-13456600-ff66-46ec-a2d2-91736d4a166e).

SharePoint list security architecture is very well, and there is know any concern for this subject and each type of security pattern can apply to data.